# video trimming in uiimagepicker

Tags: iphone, video, uiimagepickercontroller, trim

I was able trim the video when i used the photo library source type. But when I use the camera source type trimmed video appears to be saved. but when i play the saved video it is not trimmed. Can any one pls help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't use uiimagepicker AND get the edited video.  You have to use UIVideoEditorController.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIVideoEditorController